# Extract data frames from list and name them

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames with daily average temperatures from a few locations. Each data frame is 360-365 entries long and looks something like this

| Airport | Day | Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RJOO | 1998-01-01 | 12 |

I made the list from a few datasets so that I could perform calculations on them all at once like

```
weathers<-list(France, Greece)
```

I would like to be able to pull them out and save them as new files. In this case it would mean having two named France and Greece. The most I've been able to do is create a new column with the name in every entry.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is your goal here. You made a list of dataframes using `weathers<-c(France, Greece)` and now you want to extract dataframes from `weathers` ?

Answer (score 2):

there are several things going on here. You could find many friends, if you provide a reproducible example and let us know where things go wrong.
The following is a `{tidyverse}` based approach. It works with creating a nested table for each of your countries.
I hope it gets you where you want to go and you can adapt it to your problem.

**1.) get going**
As a first exercise bind your various dataframes into a large one. I simulate some data to establish a dataframe. Read up on how to do this, if this is already an issue for you.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(666) # set seed and simulate data ---------------------------------
Airport <- rep(c("RJOO","LFPG","EHAM"), 5)
Day <- sample(c( as.POSIXct("1998-01-01")
                 ,as.POSIXct("1998-01-02")
                 ,as.POSIXct("1998-01-03") ), 15, replace = TRUE)
Average <- sample(c(12:25), 15, replace = TRUE)

df <- tibble(Airport, Day, Average)
```

This yields:

```
df
# A tibble: 15 x 3
   Airport Day                 Average
   <chr>   <dttm>                <int>
 1 RJOO    1998-01-02 00:00:00      19
 2 LFPG    1998-01-02 00:00:00      18
 3 EHAM    1998-01-03 00:00:00      13
 4 RJOO    1998-01-03 00:00:00      12
 5 LFPG    1998-01-02 00:00:00      21
 6 EHAM    1998-01-01 00:00:00      17
 7 RJOO    1998-01-01 00:00:00      19
 8 LFPG    1998-01-01 00:00:00      20
 9 EHAM    1998-01-02 00:00:00      15
10 RJOO    1998-01-03 00:00:00      22
11 LFPG    1998-01-01 00:00:00      24
12 EHAM    1998-01-01 00:00:00      19
13 RJOO    1998-01-03 00:00:00      21
14 LFPG    1998-01-03 00:00:00      19
15 EHAM    1998-01-02 00:00:00      18
```

**2.) associating country names** it is not clear from your example how you associate the country names. I assume you know your way around. The airport ICAO location indicators (basically the first or first 2 letters) give you the country. If you have a lookup table you can merge the location indicator (4-letter-code, RJOO) with the country. You can merge lookup tables with `{dplyr}`'s `left_join()`.

Being lazy I use a `case_when()` to roll on. obviously, you might have to do this differently.

```
# associate country names with data
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Country = case_when(    # a lazy look up for country name creation -----
                  Airport == "RJOO" ~ "Japan"
                , Airport == "LFPG" ~ "France"
                , Airport == "EHAM" ~ "Netherlands"
                , TRUE ~ as.character(NA) )
   ) #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You know have the following:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   Airport Day                 Average Country    
   <chr>   <dttm>                <int> <chr>      
 1 RJOO    1998-01-02 00:00:00      19 Japan      
 2 LFPG    1998-01-02 00:00:00      18 France     
 3 EHAM    1998-01-03 00:00:00      13 Netherlands
 4 RJOO    1998-01-03 00:00:00      12 Japan      
 5 LFPG    1998-01-02 00:00:00      21 France     
 6 EHAM    1998-01-01 00:00:00      17 Netherlands
 7 RJOO    1998-01-01 00:00:00      19 Japan      
 8 LFPG    1998-01-01 00:00:00      20 France     
 9 EHAM    1998-01-02 00:00:00      15 Netherlands
10 RJOO    1998-01-03 00:00:00      22 Japan      
11 LFPG    1998-01-01 00:00:00      24 France     
12 EHAM    1998-01-01 00:00:00      19 Netherlands
13 RJOO    1998-01-03 00:00:00      21 Japan      
14 LFPG    1998-01-03 00:00:00      19 France     
15 EHAM    1998-01-02 00:00:00      18 Netherlands
```

**3.) nested data frame**
Creation of a nested data frame is straightforward.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Country) %>% nest()
df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Country [3]
  Country     data            
  <chr>       <list>          
1 Japan       <tibble [5 x 3]>
2 France      <tibble [5 x 3]>
3 Netherlands <tibble [5 x 3]>
```

**4.) using a nested table for writing out parts**
First we create a function that helps us with writing out the country part of our data frame/tibble.

```
# utility function to write out country parts
write_country <- function(.ctry, .data){
  fn <- paste0(.ctry, ".csv")   # construct a filename to your liking
  readr::write_csv(.data, fn) 
}

# as we write out and the function does not return
# we use purrr's walk instead of map to iterate over the nested data
walk2( .x = df$Country       # you have 2 variables, thus use walk2
     , .y = df$data          # define .x and .y vector
     , .f = ~ write_country(.x, .y)  # supply your function, watch the tilde ~
)

# you will now see 3 csv files: Japan.csv, France.csv, and Netherlands.csv
```

This recipe should work for you.
Just make sure to define the filename also considering the folder structure and where you want to save it out, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:
I had a list of just the file names which I initially used to import the unedited CSVs in the first place.

```
filenames <- gsub("\\.csv$","", list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")) 
for(i in filenames){
assign(i, read.csv(paste(i, ".csv", sep="")))
}
```

You could probably make this in a different way if you imported them differently like something like

```
filenames<-c("France", "Greece")

airport="LFMD"
days=as.Date("1988-2-15")
temperature=3
France<-data.frame(airport,days,temperature)


airport2="LGEL"
days2=as.Date("1994-1-11")
temperature2=15
Greece<-data.frame(airport2,days2,temperature2)

mylist<-list(France, Greece)
```

After passing this through several functions, in order to save the edited ones to file

```
    for(i in 1:length(filenames)){
  write.csv(mylist[[i]], file = paste0("D:/Weather/Modified/", filenames[i],".csv"), row.names = TRUE)
}
```

Which gives me the saved files with the names I desire.